# Service object return

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Here is a little problem that I assume pops up ALOT in RIA's, Flex/AS3 especially. Allow me to explain, lets assume we have a complex object Car.

```
Car
{
   name:String;
   creationDate:Date;
   engineSize:String;
   pastOwners:Array;
   maintenenceOperations:Array
}
```

Now lets say my application updates a Car object by changing it's name and sends it out to the service.  My question is how do you handle the returning of the object and updating the Car object present on the application side.  Do you slog it and write the boilerplate for each class ?  How do you handle if a property is lazy loaded ?

I have done it before writing the boilerplate update code, I just didn't want to go on reinventing the square wheel if there is a better way.

A request of an example of the update method was requested so here it is.  It isn't complete with all aspects, but it captures the idea that you have an existing Car object, and you pass the new service object to it to rectify the differences.

```
[Bindable]
[RemoteClass("com.stackoverflow.example")]
public class Car
{
    public var name:String;
    public var engineSize:String;
    public var maintenenceOperations:Array;
    public var owner:Owner;

    public function update( value:Car ):void
    {
        if( value != null )
        {
            this.name = value.name; 
            this.engineSize = value.engineSize;  
            if( this.owner != null )
            {
                this.owner.update( value );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your boilerplate update code?

Comment: @Taurayi  I updated the question with an example of update code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple, most of the time there is no need to handle the return of an object that was sent to the service to be updated.

If the object is modified by the service while it is been updated, get the result object and replace the hole flex object instead of checking its properties for change.

Comment: Thanks @GustavoFSx I may have to do that.  It will require a good amount of bookkeeping though.  Let's say you update a maintenanceOperation pertaining to a Car.  We now have to find that Car object in our dictionary, and replace the maintenance operation with the returned one.  I do enjoy the "Keep it simple" aspect, sometimes I get so bogged down I don't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: I agree--working with entire objects is a way to stay grounded in good object-oriented design and reduce tight coupling.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you need some sort of ID (unique) that relates to the object.  When the server returns, you can then look through an associative array (Dictionary) for that object id and update the appropriate properties.

Long answer, it *really* depends what you're trying to accomplish and how.  There are many answers to this question, but it's up to you to find it which way is best for your specific case.

Comment: Thanks @J_A_X.  I am thinking that I may go for replacing the entire object.  Then when I replace the object, fire off a "providerChangeEvent" from my managers to let the models and presenters know they need to refresh.  Since they hold a reference to the old IUID object, they can search for the updated one and refresh their views/data. <br/>  By having a merge method in my application, the updating can be explicitly avoided and done implicitly since the reference would be the same.